# In an LLC Partnership, does each partner report expenses in the partnership tax return or personal tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, partnership

Does each partner report their business expenses in the LLC partnership tax return or their personal return? Does the amount each partner reports as a business expense, affect the ownership in the partnership in any way?

Answer (score 2):

The LLC will file its own business taxes which may or may not have business level income and expenses.  At the end, the LLC will issue Schedule K-1 tax forms to the members, that based on their percentage ownership, will reflect the percentage share of the income/losses.

From an individual standpoint, the members need only worry about the K-1 form they receive.  This has quite a few pass-through categories from the LLC, but the Income/Loss may be the only used one.  The individual will likely include the K-1 by filing a Schedule-E along with their 1040 form.  The 1040 Schedule-E has some ability to deduct expenses as an individual.

Generally it's best not to commingle expenses.  Additional schedule-E expense reporting is generally for non-reimbursed, but related business expenses.  If a member paid certain fees for the LLC, it is better for the LLC to reimburse him and then deduct the expense properly.  Schedule-E is on a non-LLC, personal level.